# Simple subtraction and cast question

Tags: c#, casting

Why won't this simple subtraction work?

```
int MyPageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cboPageNumber.SelectedItem);
MyPageNumber += (MyPageNumber - 1); //does not work
int MyNewPageNumber = MyPageNumber - 1; /works
```

I was also hoping someone could tell me why this gives me a "red line" for not being able to do a cast:

```
short MyPageNumber = Convert.ToInt16(cboPageNumber.SelectedItem);
MyPageNumber += MyPageNumber - ((short) 1); //does not work says can't cast
```

What am I not understanding?  Is the + turning it into a String in the examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at exactly what this does:

```
MyPageNumber += (MyPageNumber - 1);
```

It *adds* MyPageNumber-1 to the existing value. So if MyPageNumber is 5, you end up with 9 instead of the 4 which you presumably want.

Now for the second problem, you've basically got a situation equivalent to this:

```
short x = 5;
short y = 10;
short z = x - y;
```

It looks okay, but C# doesn't actually have a subtraction operator for shorts - it only has it on ints, so it's implicitly converting both `x` and `y` to `int`. The result is then an `int` too, which you can't assign back to `z`. You need:

```
short z = (short) (x - y);
```

(or the equivalent with your real variable names).

Answer (score 1):

Define "doesn't work" - seems fine to me... in particular:

```
int MyPageNumber = Convert.ToInt32("3");
MyPageNumber += (MyPageNumber - 1); // 5 as expected
```

Re the second; all `short` arithmetic results in an int, due to CPU efficiencies etc; try:

```
MyPageNumber += (short)(MyPageNumber - ((short)1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If MyPageNumber equals 3, the first equation would produce 5, the second would produce 2.

Also, you shouldn't need to cast a 1 to short ... the cast is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyPageNumber += (MyPageNumber - 1);
```

Means reduce MyPageNumber by one, then add the result of that to the old value of MyPageNumber.

For example if MypageNumber is 3:

3 += (3 - 1) 
3 += 2
5

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
short magicNumber=1;
MyPageNumber +=MyPageNumber-magicNumber;
```

You could also do

```
MyPageNumber += (short)(MyPageNumber-1);
```

See this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4(VS.80).aspx)