# Subtracting int from double leads to an error

Tags: c#, int, double, subtraction

I have an int and a double, but as soon as I try to subtract the integer from the double, the following error is thrown:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Now lets look at the code:

```
double TotalNoRegis = values.Sum(); // This is a LIST and its = 1569
string otherFe ="600";
double totalafter;
if(otherFe != string.Empty || otherFe!= "") // This part works fine
{
    totalafter =  TotalNoRegis - Convert.ToInt32(otherFe); // Here the error is thrown
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I looked at this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595399/simple-subtraction-and-cast-question?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), which is basically the same thing: `int x = 1` and `int y = 2` and then `int this = x-y;`

Please let me know if you know the issue here.

Comment: Technically String.Empty and "" are identical, you would be better suited to use string.IsNullOrEmpty.

Comment: Oh yeah but it is working for that part it is going in that `{}` going in there and shows that error in there

Comment: for the `IF()` its working fine its going in the `{}` the Error it shows is where `totalafter =  TotalNoRegis` I ran the code live time and tracked each line in Visual studio

Comment: @Dominik I tried as you suggested `Double.Parse` and its still showing the same error I will add the image of the Error in the question too

Comment: Your code sample doesn't demonstrate the issue. The error suggests the value of `otherFe` contains non-numeric characters or spaces. Show a proper example.

Comment: You can never expect parsing will work. You have to *asume* the user will input pure garbage. That parse throws Exceptions so easily is a vexing behavior. So vexing, they added TryParse in .NET 2.0. It is literally an example for Vexing Exceptions (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx). You should always parse the value first thing after input by the user. Do not keep strings around in memory. Try to parse them. And if that fails, stop.

Comment: FYI string.IsNullOrEmpty and string.IsNullOrWhitespace exist.

Comment: @Christopher To add to your answer, they even introduced .TryParse(input, out type variable) to make using them even easier.

Comment: @Christopher These values are coming from the database and I am removing any unwanted values with in the string so its pure number no word no space no nothing I am using string.Replace method to do so all I need to combine the values and show the total

Comment: @Maxi Wait, what...!

Comment: @Equalsk `String otherFe  ="600"` has spaces? non-numeric characters and I am converting it to INT and it is doing that with no issue

Comment: `otherFe != string.Empty || otherFe!= ""` That code is nonsensical. `string.Empty` and `""` are *the same string*.

Comment: The problem is not repro. Your code works just fine.

Comment: The real problem has nothing to do with the subtraction. You're passing a bad string to ToInt32. You should use `TryParse` instead.

Comment: No, you're not understanding what I'm saying. The code you've shown is obviously not the real code and doesn't reproduce the issue, in the real code someone is entering something like "600abc" which throws the error.

Comment: @Maxi: "These values are coming from the database" Why ON EARTH do you need to parse values from a Database? Your design sounds utterly busted if you do not even use the numerical types to store numbers in the Database. Fix that problem first. Anything else becomes a non-issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Lots.

```
if(otherFe != string.Empty || otherFe!= "") // This part works fine
```

That's nonsensical code. `string.Empty` and `""` are *the same string*.

Instead use

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(otherFe))
```

Moving on:

```
totalafter =  TotalNoRegis - Convert.ToInt32(otherFe); // Here the error is thrown
```

You claim that the error is the subtraction, but it is not.  The problem is in the `ToInt32`. You are passing some other string than the one you are showing.

The way I like to do this is by making an extension method:

```
static public class Extensions 
{
    public static int? ParseAsInteger(this string s) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return null;
        int i;
        return int.TryParse(s, out i) ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
    }
    // Similarly write `ParseAsDouble` and so on.
}
```

Now you have an extension you can use:

```
double? totalAfter = TotalNoRegis - otherFe.ParseAsInteger();
```

(Or `ParseAsDouble`, or whatever.)

If otherFe was valid, then `totalAfter` has the total; if it was not, then it is `null`.

The lesson here is: **move the type conversion logic into its own method which you can independently test**.  Then the logic at the call site of that method becomes simpler and easier to follow.

Comment: «string.Empty and "" are the same string.» - I remember we had issues with Windows Workflow Foundation when moving from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4. I can't recall the details (I think it was a bug in WF that we reported to Microsoft) but if you replaced `string.Empty` with two double quotes `""` in certain objects, the problem magically disappeared.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: They are not necessarily *reference equal* (that is, interned).  But they are always value equal.

Comment: In C# 7.0, you can merge the `TryParse` call with the declaration of `i` with `int.TryParse(s, out int i)`.  In either case, you can omit the null check in favor of letting TryParse return false on nulls.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an integer instead of a double, especially if you don't have a reason to use the double.  So to rectify, you could simply do the following.

```
int total = values.Sum();
var other = "6000";

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(other))
     if(int.TryParse(other, out int subtractor))
          total -= subtractor;
```

If you require a double, then use but if you don't why bother?  Also, you are subtracting fifteen hundred items from six thousand, your total after will always be negative or often be negative.  Is that your desired intent?

Something to note, with the `TryParse` if it fails it'll skip the subtraction rather than fail like parse or convert would do. Also do you want the sum of the list or count?

Comment: It is 600 it was a mistake one extra 0 sorry about that and yes it could be double the values that gets calculated could be anything thing in double too and I need to combine and show a total in this case